# Is the following function continuously differentiable?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $f(x,y)=\frac{x^4+2y^4}{x^2+y^2}$, with $f(0,0)=0$. Is this function continuously differentiable at $(0,0)$?

So I understand that for differentiability at a point of a function like this the definition can be written as requiring the following limit to be true.
\begin{align*}
\lim_{(h,k)\rightarrow (0,0)}\frac{f(x_0+h,y_0+k)-f(x_0,y_0)-f_x(x_0,y_0)h-f_y(x_0,y_0)k}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}=0
\end{align*}
And I can plug in all the requisite calculations and sure enough this functions is differentiable at $(0,0)$ which is somewhat obvious. In any case I am at a loss for what how to test whether or not the function is continuously differentiable at $(0,0)$. I mean my understanding is that we are trying to say that the derivative itself is continuous at $(0,0)$. I'm not sure how to work this out. I'm sure there is some straightforward connection I'm not making. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct; you would like to show that the derivative is continuous at $(0,0)$. 
This is equivalent to showing each partial derivative is continuous at $(0,0)$.
In other words, you need to show
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)} f_x(x,y) = f_x(0,0), \quad \lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}f_y(x,y) = f_y(0,0).
$$
Note that this will basically be the same work you did to show $f$ is continuous at $(0,0)$; for example:
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)} f_x(x,y) = \lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left(\frac{x^4+2y^4}{x^2+y^2} \right) = \lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)} \frac{(x^2+y^2)4x^3-(x^4+2y^4)2x}{(x^2+y^2)^2} = 0 = f_x(0,0).
$$